# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 2.'

Tags: c#, sql, database, exception, datatable

Can you help me. Im getting error from this where I get out of range exception. I've checked the Column name "fYearLevel" same as what I've put into the query and they also have the same data type.

```
sql = "SELECT fName, fCourse, fYearLevel, fMajor, fScholarship, fBirthdate, fEmailAddress, fAddress, fContactNo FROM tblstudents WHERE fIDno = @id";
        List<MySqlParameter> paramList = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", txtIDNo.Text));
        config.ParametersCommand(sql, paramList);
        dtgStudents.DataSource = config.dt;
        if (config.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            
            txtName.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
            cmbCourse.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(1);
            cmbYearLevel.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(2).ToString();// error here
            cmbMajor.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(3);
            cmbScholarship.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(4);
            dateTimeBirthdate.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(5).ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(6);
            txtAddress.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(7);
            txtContactNo.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(8);
            
        }
```

I also set my data source to my datagridview and its works fine. Only when it goes to setting  where I got my error
It gets out of range exception and cannot find the column but if I remove Column "fCourse" it works fine.

```
sql = "SELECT fName, fCourse, fYearLevel, fMajor, fScholarship, fBirthdate, fEmailAddress, fAddress, fContactNo FROM tblstudents WHERE fIDno = @id";
        List<MySqlParameter> paramList = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", txtIDNo.Text));
        config.ParametersCommand(sql, paramList);
        dtgStudents.DataSource = config.dt;
        if (config.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            
            txtName.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
            //cmbCourse.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(1);
            cmbYearLevel.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<int>(2).ToString();// all data down will be set
            cmbMajor.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(3);
            cmbScholarship.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(4);
            dateTimeBirthdate.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(5).ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(6);
            txtAddress.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(7);
            txtContactNo.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(8);
            
        }
```

Comment: Make object (or string) instead of int : config.dt.Rows[0].Field<object>(2).ToString();

Comment: @jdweng I changed it to <object> but still cannot find column.

Comment: How many columns are in the table?  Looks like table only has one column.

Comment: @jdweng Should have 9 columns I have projected it to my datagridview and all columns is there including that column where I got my error.

Comment: You are reading in code from the datatable config.dt.

Comment: @jdweng I experimented a bit and reversed the order like I put txtContactNo.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(8)  first to txtName.Text = config.dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0) and it WORKED!!. How did this happen?

Comment: Maybe a typo error that you corrected.  Put back to original order.